# Error running Spring Batch Admin on Tomcat 6/7

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am getting this error when running a Spring Batch Admin template project created via STS 3.2 on vanilla Tomcat 6/7 on RedHat Linux:

```
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [batch-L.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I have no idea where that file is coming from. I tried searching for the file but to no success. Also, I need to add, that when running the same *war file on my local machine, everything works fine.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch Admin uses a system variable `ENVIRONMENT` to determine what properties file to load.  By default, (if the variable isn't set), it will look for an HSQLDB version named batch-hsqldb.properties.  In your case, it looks like the ENVIRONMENT variable is being set to the letter L.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact solution.